# How to use Varray or cursor or any other array in decode function to compare the values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I want to compare the last_name values in emp_x table, name column for first 3 character if match any of the records then i want to return that value from emp_x table.

Below is my tables and records:

```
select substr(x.last_name,1,3) from employee x;

Mathews
Smith
Rice
Black
Green
Larry
Cat

select * from emp_x;

Mataaa
Mmitta
Smitta
Riceeeee

Expected Result:
select decode(substr(x.last_name,1,3), substr(x.last_name,1,3), (select name from emp_x y where y.name like substr(x.last_name,1,3)||'%'),x.last_name) from employee x;

Mataaa
Smitta
Riceeeee
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I am getting the exact result but is there any other best way to use it in pl/sql procedure.

say for example, I am taking the 'Mathews' last_name value from employee table and read the first 3 digit and comparing in emp_x table and getting the Mataa value as result in the decode function above.

Instead of selecting values from table can we use any array or cursor to compare and get the values from varaible in pl/SQL Procedure...

Please help to resolve this..

Answer (score 1):

I know this code is not the best solution, it's sort of work(ish) in nature. Anyways I wrote it to just pass some time at work, and I hope even if its not the complete solution, you get an idea regarding what you wanna achieve

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 IS select substr(x.last_name,1,3) from employee x;
c1_rec c1%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR c2 IS select * from emp_x;
c2_rec c2%ROWTYPE;
l_name employee.last_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
FOR c1_rec IN c1
LOOP
FOR c2_rec IN c2
LOOP
IF(c1_rec.last_name == c2_rec.name) THEN
SELECT last_name into l_name from EMPLOYEE where substr(last_name,1,3) = c1_rec.last_name;
dbms_output.put_line(l_name);
ELSE
dbms_output.put_line("NULL");
END IF; 
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line("exception occured");
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather stick with this approach:

```
SQL> with employee as
  2   (select 'Mathews' name from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 'Smith' from dual
  5    union all
  6    select 'Rice' from dual
  7    union all
  8    select 'Black' from dual
  9    union all
10    select 'Green' from dual
11    union all
12    select 'Larry' from dual
13    union all
14    select 'Cat' from dual),
15  emp_x as
16   (select 'Mataaa' pattern from dual
17    union all
18    select 'Mmitta' from dual
19    union all
20    select 'Smitta' from dual
21    union all
22    select 'Riceeeee' from dual)
23  select nvl(ex.pattern, 'NULL') result
24    from employee e
25    left outer join emp_x ex
26      on substr(ex.pattern, 1, 3) = substr(e.name, 1, 3);

RESULT
--------
Mataaa
Smitta
Riceeeee
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
7 rows selected
```

You didn't provide any information about how big are your tables, but anyway hash join in this query would be much faster then any procedural code. Of course if you need to use it in some procedure you could wrap it in cursor:

```
for c1 in (select ...)
loop
 dbms_output.put_line(c1.result);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for comparing collections using cursors:

declare

cursor c1 is

select last_name ls from empc;

type x is table of employees.last_name%type;

x1 x := x();

cnt integer :=0;

begin

for z in c1 loop

cnt := cnt +1;

x1.extend;

x1(cnt) := z.ls;

if x1(cnt) is  NULL then

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ASHISH');

end if;

dbms_output.put_line(cnt || ' '|| x1(cnt));

end loop;

end;